# How to achieve absolute positioning in Javafx (FXML)

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Ok lets just assume I wanted to have the following layout:

```
<GridPane>
    <Button></Button>
    <Button></Button>
<GridPane/>

<HBox>
    <Label></Label>
<HBox/>
```

Now, in HTML I would simply apply `position: absolute` via css and one of the two containers would detache from the normal document flow allowing it to float around without pushing its siblings aside. I am trying to achieve something similar but im on it for hours already.

According to the Oracle documentation this can be achieved with either StackPane, which I dont want because I want the other container unaffected) or I could use a raw Pane node which somehow acts crazy because well, its a base class. The documentation about the pane also says:

*This class may be used directly in cases where absolute positioning of children*

and well ***of children*** doesnt sound good...as in my case it has to be the direct container.

**So my question is**: how can I achieve absolute positioning without hacking around with too much math?

Could localToScene() be what I want?

*Transforms a bounds from the local coordinate space of this Node into the coordinate space of its scene.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My impression is that you are still thinking in HTML-terms and not JavaFX-Terms. For example in JavaFX there is no "normal document flow". Everything has to be put into some layout container and this container determines how things are layed out and there is nothing wrong with using a Pane directly if you have to. Although I am not sure what your actual use-case is, I think you might want to have a look at the AnchorPane.

Comment: I think that pretty much answers it. Just one little side question. Any good xml reference out there where I can see all the available FXML tags and properties such as alignment, prefWidth etc? The oracle documentation seems pretty poor and its really hard finding the FXML equivalents of javafx code.

Comment: This reference http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/jfxpub-fxml_get_started.htm summarizes the available docs from Oracle and I do not know any better documentation. An option would be to not use FXML directly but to use SceneBuilder to create your views. (Download the latest SceneBuilder from Gluon not Oracle!)

Comment: Ya but im a hardcoder so I hate helper tools hehe. Ya that documentation is really bad, nothing like the MDN :D

Comment: I had another question but I planned to keep it seperate. Maybe you are interested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818022/fxml-have-1-child-fixed-width-while-second-is-responsive-both-horizonzally-alig